How to configure NLog to log only Errors in the Windows syslog?
I'm trying to log only Errors into the Windows syslog (events viewer), I tried many solutions but none of them run as expected. I still see warning messages in the Windows syslog.
It's an Asp.Net Core project (nuget 2.2.0) with NLog 5.2.8, NLog.Web.AspNetCore, Version=4.0.0.0.
I don't have any a content related to log configuration in my appsettings.json file and here is the content of my nglog.config file.
What am I missing?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true">
   <extensions>
      <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
      <add assembly="NLog.WindowsEventLog"/>
   </extensions>

   <targets>
      <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="Backoffice_template.log" layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring} |action: ${aspnet-mvc-action} |user: ${aspnet-user-identity}" archiveEvery="Day" encoding="utf-8"
                   archiveNumbering = "Date"
                   archiveDateFormat = "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss" archiveOldFileOnStartup="false" maxArchiveDays="30" />
      <target name="EventLog" xsi:type="EventLog">
         <logLevel>Error</logLevel>
      </target>
      <target xsi:type="Console" name="lifetimeConsole" layout="${MicrosoftConsoleLayout}" />
   </targets>

   <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" maxLevel="Warning" writeTo="allfile" />
      <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxLevel="Warning" final="true" />
      <logger name="System.Net.Http.*" maxlevel="Info" />
      <logger name="Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime" minlevel="Info" writeTo="lifetimeConsole, ownFile-web" final="true" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="EventLog" final="true" />
   </rules>
</nlog>

Logger is created like this:
var logger = LogManager.Setup().GetCurrentClassLogger();

Strange fact, it's running as expected if I add this to appsettings.json:
   "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
         "Default": "Information",
         "Microsoft": "Warning",
         "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      },
      "EventLog": {
         "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Error"
         }
      }
   },

And if I use my original nlog.config file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
     >
   <extensions>
      <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
   </extensions>

   <targets>
           <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" 
                   fileName="Backoffice_template.log"
                   layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring} |action: ${aspnet-mvc-action} |user: ${aspnet-user-identity}" 
                   archiveEvery="Day"
                   encoding="utf-8"
                   archiveNumbering = "Date"
                   archiveDateFormat = "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"
                   archiveOldFileOnStartup="false"
                   maxArchiveDays="30"
                   />

       <target xsi:type="Console" name="lifetimeConsole" layout="${MicrosoftConsoleLayout}" />
   </targets>

   <rules>
       <!--Do not change this value to set log level for BackOffice, instead change LogLevel.Default in appsettings.json -->
       <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />
       <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxLevel="Warning" final="true" />
       <logger name="System.Net.Http.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />
       <logger name="Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime" minlevel="Info" writeTo="lifetimeConsole" final="true" />
   </rules>
</nlog>

In summary, I have been asked to move the eventlog configuration from the appsettings.json to the NLog but I don't succeed to to it.

When troubleshooting NLog then it is a good idea to enable throwConfigExceptions="true" and look at NLog InternalLogger for clues.

As stated on this page, when using Asp.Net Core (on Windows), there are some log providers that are automatically added, so trying to configure then in NLog is useless:

The default ASP.NET Core web app templates call
WebApplication.CreateBuilder, which adds the following logging
providers:
Console
Debug
EventSource
EventLog: Windows only


